# Spring Data - How to reuse repository in repository fragment?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

*Update*: the following is using Spring Boot 2.1.0

I have a Spring Data repository and I am trying to provide some custom functionality to it, following the [fragments example from the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behavior).

So I've added an extra interface to the repository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>, UserExtraLogic {
    User findByFirstNameAndLastName(String firstName, String lastName);
}
```

with this custom interface:

```
interface UserExtraLogic {
    void ensureHasAccess();
}
```

and its implementation:

```
class UserExtraLogicImpl implements UserExtraLogic {
    public void ensureHasAccess() {
    }
}
```

The problem is that I would like to be able to use my repositories inside `UserExtraLogicImpl`, so that I can reuse query methods like `findByFirstNameAndLastName` without having to write them by myself with `EntityManager`. So I tried this:

```
class UserExrtaLogicImpl implements UserExtraLogic {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
}
```

But then the application does not start. I get a NullPointerException, but I think it's just Spring getting into a cycle trying to resolve these dependencies.

Is what I'm trying to do possible? Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Hello. Could you please provide the stacktrace of the exception ? Does your interface have `@Repository` annotation ? Did you enable JPA repositories in your configuration ?

Comment: Hi Mickael, the stacktrace is too long and it doesn't fit the question. I have not added the `@Repository` annotation and I have not enabled "JPA repositories" (I don't know what that means).

Please note that everything works as expected, until the moment I try to autowire the `UserRepository` inside the fragment.

Comment: Could you please explain what "works" ? Do you mean you have no exceptions ? Or do you mean you can actually use the repositories ?

Comment: Hi Mikael, when I say "works", I mean that the data access works as expected.

I'm currently using EntityManager and manually creating queries using the Java Persistence Query Language inside the fragments. That's the part I'd like to avoid, because now I'm implementing with EntityManager a method that I normally get for free (e.g. `findByFirstNameAndLastName`).

Comment: @NikolaosGeorgiou had you solved this?

Comment: @NikolaosGeorgiou Circular dependency stack trace is very different from NPE. And in that case, the application would not even start. I doubt that you don't have a circular dependency problem. I suspect that one of your beans is not getting initialized and that is throwing an NPE when you are calling some method on that non-initialized bean. Use the debugger mode to see which variable is null. It has to be any of the autowired beans.

Answer (score 4):

I have the exactly the same code patterns and encounter the same problem in a recent project and I finally solve it by using `@Lazy` to lazy initialise `UserRepository` :

```
class UserExrtaLogicImpl implements UserExtraLogic {

    @Lazy
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

}
```

Comment: You are right. Circular dependency problem can be solved by `@Lazy` but I highly doubt that @Nikolaos Georgiou has that problem. The problem statement they described does not have a circular dependency problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can lazily load your repository with `ObjectFactory<T>` (Spring concept) or `Provider<T>` (standard java api).

```
class UserExrtaLogicImpl implements UserExtraLogic {
    @Autowired
    private ObjectFactory<UserRepository> userRepository;

    public void soSomething() {
         userRepository().getObject().findById(xxx);
    }
}
```

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn I had tried a similar approach which hadn't worked due to `getObject()` being called too early. This does work. That being said, it's not as idiomatic as `@Lazy` and definitely not identical, so the downvote isn't warranted.

Comment: `getObject() being called too early.` -> So you may show how do you call it early by code. If you access it like my example, it's not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

### Repositories enablement

From [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.namespace)

If you're using Spring XML configuration, you should have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

  <jpa:repositories base-package="com.acme.repositories" />

</beans>
```

If you're using Java configuration instead, you should have this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.acme.repositories")
class ApplicationConfiguration {

  @Bean
  EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
    // …
  }
}
```

### Repositories configuration

Also, you need to add `@Repository` annotation on your repositories:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>, UserExtraLogic {
    User findByFirstNameAndLastName(String firstName, String lastName);
}
```

**Explanation**

From [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.namespace)

> Using the `repositories` element looks up Spring Data repositories as
>   described in [“Creating Repository Instances”](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.create-instances). Beyond that, it
>   activates persistence exception translation for all beans annotated
>   with `@Repository`, to let exceptions being thrown by the JPA
>   persistence providers be converted into Spring’s `DataAccessException`
>   hierarchy.

Comment: Hi Mickael, thank you for the help. I realise that I forgot to mention that my app is in Spring Boot 2.1.0. I'm sorry I forgot to mention it. I think what you're mentioning is already provided for me by Spring Boot.

Comment: This is incorrect. I'm also seeing NPEs triggered from repository fragment code when trying to access derived query methods in the base repository.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to this in documentation.

```
Extending the fragment interface with your repository interface combines the CRUD and custom functionality and makes it available to clients.
```

When you extend your fragment interface, your final repository will include that as well. That is the benift of it. If you want to access original repository logic I can suggest you 3 methods.

1. Add your query in your fragment and extend it in your repository. Then in your service method include an aggregated method. In that method write your logic.
2. In your custom interface, inlude your repository and do not extend your custom interface in repository.
3. Use a decorator class. Delegate all the methods to repository and combine custom logic with repository.

Do not include circular dependencies as it is not a good practise.